# Mozilla tag redundant

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems to me that the tag [mozilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) is not used well, and should be removed. All of the mozilla questions are (or should be) tagged with either [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/firefox) or [thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/thunderbird), and not with [mozilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mozilla). Should the tag be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are still some questions, that are more generic "mozilla" related questions, I have gone through and retaged most that were purely "Firefox" or "Thunderbird" questions.

[mozilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mozilla) description:

> Can refer to either the Mozilla project or Mozilla Foundation. They
>   produce a variety of software including Firefox and Thunderbird; thus,
>   questions about a particular Mozilla program (versus the organization
>   itself) should use a more specific tag.

As far as removing it, I think it still serves a specific purpose.

Some examples:

[What is Mozilla XPCOM and how I install it on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164218/what-is-mozilla-xpcom-and-how-i-install-it-on-ubuntu)

[Where can I find Mozilla NSPR Package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12486/where-can-i-find-mozilla-nspr-package)

So there are some things that seem to be Mozilla specific.

This is in the air (my opinion) as far as the Mozilla usage:

[Recover Firefox sync data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103731/recover-firefox-sync-data) This seems mostly to be about Firefox at first glance, but It also is about the Sync service that they provide. May or may not need the tag.